# Why is there no Array.IsNullOrEmpty() method?

Tags: arrays, null, isnullorempty

Can anyone point out a reason for the absence of a `System.Array.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Array value)`, just like there is a `System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(System.String value)`?

I know you can easily define this as an extension method, but then the syntax becomes `somearray.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of `Array.IsNullOrEmpty(somearray)`. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: I prefer somearray.IsNullOrEmpty() syntax.